# 1 modem 2 routers with independant networks

Tags: networking, router, modem

Ok I have 2 routers and one modem. (I also have a switch handy) I would like to connect both routers to the modem. The only catch is I don't want both networks down if one router stops working or is having maintenance on it.

my current set up is like this:
[1 modem, 2 routers, 2 different networks](https://superuser.com/questions/565635/1-modem-2-routers-2-different-networks)

But if router 1 goes offline or down nothing on router 2 will get internet.
I only have access to router 2's settings and can't see what is going on with router 1 when it stops working.
 My tech level is low in networking but mid-high on troubleshooting.

my switch is a Linksys SE2500, while router one is an Apple AirPort Extreme Base Station, and router two is Linksys EA4500

If anyone can provide me a link or a method of making 2 routers use the same IP address from one internet connection

Comment: Does the modem have an IP address or is it bridged to one of the routers?

Comment: What is the make and model of the modem?

Comment: ok the modem provides a dhcp and is a motorola

Comment: As for the physical connectivity, connect a switch to the LAN port of the modem. Then connect each router to the switch. As for Layer 3 you're going to have to figure out how to get both routers connected to the internet via the modem, assuming you're getting a single ip address from your ISP.

Comment: yes only one ip address from ISP

Comment: one thing is I don't really want the networks to communicate with each other just the internet

Comment: also the switch is un-managed

Comment: Hang on, the modem provides an IP address via DHCP in what range?  A public address or private?

Comment: where would I look to see if its private.

Comment: the modem is for use in residential customers

Answer (score 0):

This should "just work". Connect both routers WAN ports to the switch. Connect the modem's LAN port to the switch.

Comment: do you think I'll need to contact my ISP about the dhcp or connection set up from what it currently is.
For if I have to set something up on each router

Comment: No, I don't. Why would you? All devices should work in their default configurations because they're all doing exactly what they've been designed to do. The modem is giving a few devices (the routers) Internet access, as it's designed to do. The routers are giving a few devices (their LANs) Internet access, but not giving Internet-side devices access to their LAN, as they're designed to do.

Comment: I'll get back to you on the results in a couple days when I have the time. (gotta love smartphones on trains)

Comment: alright this did not work called ISP and they are claiming I will need a second IP address from them for an additional fee

Comment: This only 'just works' if the modem has a built-in router. I don't think this one does.

Comment: @MarcksThomas See the OP's comment, "*the modem provides a dhcp*".